# CSS3 Scale animation resets

Tags: html, css, css-animations

The CSS3 transition resets right away even though I'm still hovering it. Can anyone help me make this permanent and not reset while the mouse is hovering over it?

```css
.grow {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.grow:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a class="logo-icon grow" href="#">
  <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="logo">
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link is screwing it up, because it is `display: inline`.

```css
.grow { 
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    display: block; /* or display: inline-block; */
}

.grow:hover { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a class="logo-icon grow" href="#">
  <img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg" alt="logo">
</a>
```

#### But why?

Inline elements do not expand to their content's height. Block elements do:
[image]

Comment: <3 How did that even pop up in your head? I see no relations between the two lol

Comment: @SJW Haha, that behavior seemed impossible, unless the `hover` state was interrupted. And the only way I thought of for this to happen while having your cursor on it is this.

Comment: The "block" ruined anything else that was on the line but the "inline-block" did it. Thanks again man

Comment: Right, that makes sense that it can interrupt it. But how does that fix it in any way o.O? As I said they are really unrelated.

Comment: @SJW I added the explanation in my answer.

Comment: I kinda wanna +1 this for the cute lamb alone.